# How to set an Object Model on JCombox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

**EDIT**

I am having problem with some of my project that is setting an object on my JComboBox. In my JPanel called ApplicationPanel, I did this one:

```
...
if(application!=null){                    
    this.formView.setApplication(application);
}
this.formView.setPositions(positions);
this.formView.setControls(controls);
this.formView.displayControl(); //I put it here because even application is null, by default it shows all Control available when formView is shown.
this.formView.setVisible(true);
```

And in my JPanel called FormView, I created this code for putting all my Class/Object named **Control** into JComboBox:

```
public final void displayControl(){
    this.cmboControls.removeAllItems();
    this.cmboControls.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(this.controls.toArray()));
}
```

also this one:

```
public void setApplication(Application application){
    this.application = application;
    Control ctrl = findControl(application);
    System.out.println("You look for "+ctrl);
    this.cmboControls.setSelectedItem(findControl(application));
...
```

This is my code for findControl

```
private Control findControl(Candidate c){
    Control jc = null;
    System.out.println("From Candidate: control_id "+c.getPosition().getId());
    for(Control ctrl: this.controls){
        if(Objects.equals(ctrl.getId(), c.getPosition().getId())){
            System.out.println("Found Item nUm "+ctrl.getId());
            jc = ctrl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return jc;
}
```

Control class:

```
public class Control {
    private Integer id;
    private String controlCode;
    private Position position;
//Setter and Getter Plus toString()
...
```

I also search for similar problem here in stackoverflow but it also does not solve my problem. I tried to change my **JComboBox Type Parameters** from **String** into **Object** but nothing happens.

**Hope someone can point out where the error occurred.**

Comment: You set the model before you try and set the selected element? May consider providing a runnable example of what you are trying to do, it will provide greater context to you problem and improve the quality of the answers

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question without guessing. Provide `Control` and `findControl()`.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: And where is your question???

Comment: `I also search for similar problem` - what problem? Note: `setSelectedItem(...)` will only work if your custom Objects implements the `equals(...)` method.